# Bash - Retrieve ID From A String (xinput) Received From A Pipe

Tags: linux, bash

When I run the following command it returns me the information of my current mouse:-

```
$ xinput --list | grep "Mouse"
⎜   ↳ A4Tech USB Mouse                          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

What command should I execute (maybe along with some regex) that I can get an output `13` (in current case).

Something like this:-

```
$ xinput --list | grep "Mouse" | ANOTHER_COMMAND
13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  xinput --list | grep "Mouse" |grep -oP 'id=\K.*?(?=\s)'
```

Or even shorter :

```
xinput --list |grep -oP 'Mouse.*id=\K.*?(?=\s)'
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution in pure `bash` without other text processing tools.

```
$ xinput --list | grep "Mouse" | while IFS= read -r string; do [[ $string =~ ^.*id=([[:digit:]]+).*$ ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done
13
```

(or) Using a `perl` syntax

```
$ xinput --list | grep "Mouse" | perl -lne 'print "$1" if /.*id=(\d+).*/'
13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the matching of `Mouse` and the extraction of the `id=13` into a single command like `sed` or `awk` or `grep`.

**Example**

```
$ sed -n "/Mouse/ s/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p" file
13
```